# How do I eliminate errors? - zprofile no such file or directory - macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, macos-monterey

I met the errors with .zprofile. I see this one every time I open the macOS terminal.

**Terminal**

```
/Users/leo/.zprofile:6: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/leo/.zprofile:7: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

**Inside .zprofile shows:**

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.11
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

I've found similar questions and they recommend editing the .zprofile but I don't understand what exactly. Maybe there are other solutions to avoid this error displayed in the terminal or what I need to delete/edit?

Comment: It seems at some point you had homebrew installed, but now you don't (or something got changed and broke). So if you've deleted homebrew on purpose, you can comment out or delete those two `eval` lines. Or if you wanted homebrew to work, figure out why there isn't an executable named `brew` in the folder `/opt/homebrew/bin/`.

Comment: Obviously, /opt/homebrew/bin/brew does not exist (since this is exactly what the error message says). So fix this path to the correct location.